# Bootstrap 3 grid system with table component not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-system

My code works fine so I am just interested in using Bootstrap 3 grid system with my table component and I went through documentation I couldn't find anything. I do have all my `css` and `js` files. I've tried adding `row` or a `container`div tag and it still didn't work. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong ?

I have this

```
<table align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr>
<td class="col-md-4"><a href="file.html"><img src="someImage.png"/></a></td>
<td class="col-md-8"><a href="file2.html"><img src="someImage2.png"/></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For For basic styling—light padding and only horizontal dividers—add the base class .table to any <table>. see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables which also tells you: Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables.

Comment: OK, it seems you're quite confused, so let's see: what isn't working? what do you want to achieve? (and no, that col-.... inside tables won't have any effect unless you treat the tr and table elements like BS grids, but that's not the default BS behavior, so again, it would be very useful to know what are you trying to achieve)

Comment: `col-....` inside tables have effect, although not as intend by BS, when you set the width of your table (for instance to 100%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <table align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered"  >
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-4"><a href="file.html">
                    <img src="someImage.png" /></a></td>
                <td class="col-md-8"><a href="file2.html">
                    <img src="someImage2.png" /></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/OTR92APFGl)